# Mobile Layout Configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, helix3, responsive-web-design, mobile-web-design

- Joomla 3.6.5
- Helix3 Template [here](http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=helix3)

The layout of the template is as follows;

```
 - header |
 - left sidebar | main content | 
 - footer |
```

When I view my template on a mobile device (devtools) the `left sidebar` stacks first, and the `main content` is below it. How can I reverse this? I'd like the `main content` to display first.

I can't see any template configuration settings.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an option to add classes to the element wrappers? Else are you able to override the layout? If so, maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19569952/1362108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this, thanks to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569541/making-a-left-sidebar-appear-under-a-right-hand-column-on-a-mobile-with-bootstra/19569952#19569952) from @Lodder.

In the Helix3 template layout, I swapped the positions of the `left sidebar` and `main content` blocks (drag and drop).

Now the layout is like below;

```
 - header |
 - main content | left sidebar | 
 - footer |
```

Then I added a css class to each block as follows;

- main content `pull-right`
- left sidebar `pull-left`

This seems to have done the trick!